# How to use replace to get rid of numbers?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have something like:

```
/MyFile/14/file_1.txt 
/MyFile/17/file_2.txt 
/MyFile/10/file_3.txt
```

How can I use replace in regular expression? to turn them into

```
file 1
file 2
file 3
```

I've tried

```
.replace('/Myfile/\d+/', '').replace('_', '').replace('.txt', '')
```

and the output are

```
/MyFile/14/file 1 
/MyFile/17/file 2
/MyFile/10/file 3
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What flavour of regular expressions are you using?

Comment: In a lot of programming languages you need to double the backslash, because it will be interpreted *inside* the string as well.

Comment: I am using regex in python. replaceAll not worked. double the backflash not worked. If I do 

    .replace('/Myfile/', '').replace('_', ' ').replace('.txt', '')

then I have

    14/file 1 
    17/file 2
    10/file 3

how can i get rid of 

    14/
    17/
    10/

Answer (score 1):

you don't need to use several replacements, you only need to use capturing groups:

```
import re

p = re.compile(r'^.*/(.+)_(\d+)\.txt$')
repl = r'\1 \2'
result = re.sub(p, repl, yourstring)
```

Note that when you write a pattern you need to use a raw string (`r'....'`) to avoid to double backslashes.

Answer (score 1):

The following code would produce what you want given that the input data is a multiline string. It uses a regular expression and the [sub()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) method of the python `re` module.

In the regular expression [^/MyFile/\d+/file_(\d+).txt$](http://regex101.com/r/tM3aU4/1), the parenthesis define a *capturing group* which can latter be used in the replacement text using `\1` (where `1` is for 1<sup>st</sup> capturing group).

Also note the `r` prefix for the strings `r'^/MyFile/\d+/file_(\d+)\.txt$'` which means [python raw string](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals) and avoid us to escape the backslashes.

```py
import re
data = """\
/MyFile/14/file_1.txt
/MyFile/17/file_2.txt
/MyFile/10/file_3.txt
"""
re_file_number = re.compile(r'^/MyFile/\d+/file_(\d+)\.txt$', re.MULTILINE)
print re_file_number.sub(r'file \1', data)
```

produces:

```
file 1
file 2
file 3
```

Answer (score -1):

### `re` may help

```
[ x.replace( "_", " " ) for x in re.compile(  "(?<=/MyFile/[0-9][0-9]/).+(?=.txt)" ).findall( aString ) ]
```